# Появление блока при ховере с помощью CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

Появление блока при ховере (только `CSS+HTML`).

Надо чтобы при ховере на ссылку (которая в `UL>LI`- ссылка `TRAVELS`) -
появлялся второй блок (второй `nav`). Уже не знаю как сделать.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Economica:400,700); 


* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "Economica";
}



.li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    list-style: none;

}

.a1 {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.a1:hover {
    color: #A3A3A0;
    background-color: #E3E3DF;
}

#navigation {
    background-color: #33CDD4;
}

#ul {
    width: 900px;
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
}

#more {
    padding-left: 160px;
}

.li1 {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.a2 {

    text-decoration: none;
    color: #A3A3A0;
    font-size: 18px;
    top: 38px;

}

#nav {
    background-color: #E3E3DF;
    height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#ul1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
}

.a2:hover {
    color: #33CDD4; 
}

#nav {
    display: none;
}

#navigation #ul:hover ~ #nav {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul id="ul">
        <li class="li"><a class="a1" href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a class="a1" href="#">NEWS</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a class="a1" href="#">ECONOMICS</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a class="a1" href="#">LOCAL</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a class="a1" href="#">SPORT</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a class="a1" href="#">CULTURE</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a class="a1" href="#">TRAVELS</a></li>
        <li class="li" id="more"><a class="a1" href="#">MORE</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<nav id="nav" class="navigation">
    <ul id="ul1">
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">Amsterdam</a></li>
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">Bahamas</a></li>
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">Jamaica</a></li>
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">Las Vegas</a></li>
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">London</a></li>
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">Miami</a></li>
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">Montreal</a></li>
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">Paris</a></li>
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">Rome</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: По-моему, в таком виде только js

Comment: А как можно иначе? Только что-бы внешне осталось так же и работало

Comment: ul нужно делать вложенным в li. Потом пишем правило такого вида .a1:hover + ul

Comment: Как как..... располагаете всю навигацию, которая `<nav id="nav"` в тот самый свой нужный `li` прямо под ссылкой `<a class="a1" href="#">TRAVELS</a>`.....и пишите для отображения  `.a1:hover + #nav {
  display: block;  
}` ........и чуть переписываете стили под эту ситуацию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Economica:400,700); 

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "Economica";
}

.li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    list-style: none;}

.a1 {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.a1:hover {
    color: #A3A3A0;
    background-color: #E3E3DF;
}

#navigation {
    background-color: #33CDD4;
}

#ul {
    width: 900px;
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
}
li ul {display:none;}
li:hover ul {display:block;}

#more {
    padding-left: 160px;
}

.li1 {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.a2 {

    text-decoration: none;
    color: #A3A3A0;
    font-size: 18px;
    top: 38px;

}

#nav {
    background-color: #E3E3DF;
    height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#ul1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
}

.a2:hover {
    color: #33CDD4; 
}

#nav {
    display: none;
}

#navigation #ul:hover ~ #nav {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul id="ul">
        <li class="li"><a class="a1" href="#">SPORT</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a class="a1" href="#">CULTURE</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a class="a1" href="#">TRAVELS</a>
          <ul id="ul1">
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">Amsterdam</a></li>
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">Bahamas</a></li>
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">Jamaica</a></li>
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">Las Vegas</a></li>
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">London</a></li>
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">Miami</a></li>
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">Montreal</a></li>
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">Paris</a></li>
        <li class="li1"><a class="a2" href="#">Rome</a></li>
    </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```